# How to view ".snag" files?

Tags: windows-7, image-viewer

Is there any possible way to have ".snag" file (images created by the program "SnagIt" from the company "TechSmith") appear as viewable PC file images, particularly in Windows 7?

Answer (score 4):

The only program intended to view .Snag files, is [SnagIt](https://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html).

> We do NOT expect customers to share .snag/.snagproj files directly. We do not hold forth .snag/.snagproj files as formats for universal interchange.  In fact, Snagit's primary workflows are specifically designed to make it VERY easy for customers to share in universally accepted formats (.jpg/.png, etc) - and that is how we intend for it to be used.
>
> - Doug Troxell, Employee @ TechSmith

...

> You misunderstand the SNAG file, it's used to maintain any modifications the user made viable rather than having them flattened as would happen in a normal image format.  It's primary purpose is for the user to go back and change any modifications they made.  There's nothing evil in this purpose at all.  It's not for sharing but for the user to modify their captures.
>
> - Manny Carvalho, Champion

Source of quotes: [How does a non-SnagIt user view .snag files?](https://feedback.techsmith.com/techsmith/topics/how-does-a-non-snagit-user-view-snag-files)

Answer (score 4):

Open the file in a text editor like Notepad++
Take everything between **"‰PNG"** and **"END®B`‚"** and save it as a .PNG file.

In hexadecimal

`Start: 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A (as per definition)`
`End:   45 4E 44 AE 42 60 82`

[See this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#/media/File:PNG-Gradient_hex.png)

This will get you the raw screenshot without the modifications or additions.

Hope this helps.